# Как взаимодействуют компилируемые языки программирования и операционные системы?

Tags: c++, компиляция, ос, процессор

Поясните как работают компилируемые языки в взаимодействии с операционной системой.

Во всех источниках написано что код компилируется для того чтобы мог сразу отправляться на процессор. Т.е. я это представляю так что у нас физически лежит файл скомпилированный в котором подряд записаны двоичные команды условно 110101010101 - отправили на процессор, дальше 1010100110 - отправили на процессор и т.д. пока программа не закончится.

Но ведь это не так, в моей программе ведь может быть код который запрашивает выделение оперативной памяти или выделение дисковой памяти и я могу туда что-то записывать и читать. При этом мы знаем что этим занимается операционная система, а не напрямую код.

Так вот собственно вопрос, как это можно представить ? Что именно будет в скомпилированном файле ? И получается что он все таки не напрямую отправляет команды на процессор, а через операционную систему которая уже решает что делать с командой выполнять самой или отправить на процессор ? или как?

Можно ссылку\книгу где подробно почитать? Спасибо.

Comment: Но компилируется ведь под определенную ОС. А у неё есть своя [рантайм библиотека](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: В двух словах, и, возможно, не совсем точно. Компиляция выполняется под определенную ОС и определенный процессор. В результирующем файле лежат коды команд, отправляемых на процессор, и служебная информация, касающаяся загрузки кода в память, начального выделения памяти и т.п. Загруженный код последовательно отправляется в процессор на выполнения. Там, где в исходном коде встречается обращение к функциям ОС будет вызвана функция ОС (находящаяся в памяти). Внешние библиотеки - статические собраны туда же, в ваш файл, динамические подгружаются, когда понадобятся

Comment: Подробно прочитать - любые книги по ассемблеру, что бы представлять как вообще работает процессор и какие команды выполняет

Comment: @Mike можете привести пример ? Мне казалось все что я бегло просмотрел было ассемблер без участия ОС…

Comment: @ПавелКозлов Вот именно, что с точки зрения процессора особой разницы ОС это или обычный код приложения нет (если не считать защиты памяти). Так же как и нет каких то особых команд "выделить память", "записать на диск" и т.п. Для процессора все сводится к операциям с числами и ячейками памяти, плюс элементарные команды ввода/вывода (инструкции in и out) для работы с устройствами. Ядро ОС постоянно в памяти, оно включает функции работы с диском или выделения памяти по своим таблицам ее распределения. Прикладной код вызывает эти функции в ядре точно так же как вызывает собственные функции

Comment: Конечно чуть сложнее, прикладной код вызывает функции основной библиотеки, с которыми слинкован, в linux это libc, в windows несколько основных dll. А уже функции этой библиотеки вызывают функции ОС. Для intel платформы это обычно делается через прерывания. Но мог бы быть и обычный call по предопределенному фиксированному адресу

Comment: т.е. совсем грубо говоря с точки зрения процессора есть просто код, который лежит в оперативной памяти. И выглядит это так, что как будто это одна огромная программа, которая включает в себя и прикладной код всех запущенных программ и код ядра ОС и между ними происходят вызовы разных функций.

Comment: Я пытаюсь понять куда из скомпилированной программы отправляются команды. Напрямую на процессор или все же нет? Или там будет просто разные команды пример так , возьми число 5 положи в регистр такой то , возьми число 3 положи в регистр такой то, сложи эти числа , далее будет отдельная команда запросит в ОС место в оперативке и положить туда результат ? Как тогда ОС контролирует что я в своём бинарнике не запишу в какое то не принадлижащее процессу место ?

Comment: *"файл ... подряд записаны двоичные команды"* Не совсем. Посмотрите форматы исполняемых файлов, [пример](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#/media/File:ELF_Executable_and_Linkable_Format_diagram_by_Ange_Albertini.png) (и плюс [это](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)).

Comment: *"может быть код который запрашивает выделение оперативной памяти [и т.п.]"* Этим занимается не ваш код, а код стандартной библиотеки С/С++, который общается с ОС через [системные вызовы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2). *"что я в своём бинарнике не запишу в какое то не принадлижащее процессу место"* См. [сюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat т.е. если упрощать то в бинарнике записаны команды процессору, команды записи на диск\оперативку и в т.ч. команды вызова конкретных процедур ОС например выделяющих память. При этом если я не выделил память через ОС и пытаюсь что-то записать в какую либо ячейку, при записи сработает проверка на то что эта память не принадлежит текущему процессу?

Comment: Угу, вроде так. Причем если вы "немного" промахнетесь мимо памяти, которую выделели стандартной библиотекой, то программа может не упасть - потому что стандартная библиотека попросила у ОС больше памяти, чем дала вам.